# Refresh NSManagedObjectContext

Tags: objective-c, core-data, watchkit, mmwormhole

I am writing a WatchKit extension for an iPhone application. I share Core Data using App Groups. This is working, the data is shared. When a new `NSManagedObject` is created using watch I send a notification to the iPhone app that a new object was created. To do that I use `MMWormhole`. The iPhone app receives the `MMWormhole` notification and now I have to do the last step - refresh `NSManagedObjectContext`. How can I do it?

I was trying to forward notification of `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` inside `MMWormhole` notification and to use `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification` in the iPhone app, but it doesn’t work as `MMWormhole` serialize the notification and `NSManagedObject` doesn’t support it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple way is just to have the app reload its data. Re-do any fetches so that you get the latest data from the persistent store.

If you want to make it more sophisticated, do something like this:

In the watch extension, for every new/changed/deleted object,

- Call `objectID` to get the `NSManagedObjectID`
- Convert the object ID to a string `URIRepresentation`
- Pass these strings in the `MMWormhole` message

In the app, when receiving the message,

- Use `[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator managedObjectIDForURIRepresentation:]` to convert the strings back to an `NSManagedObjectID`
- Use `[NSManagedObjectContext existingObjectWithID:]` to get the managed object corresponding to the object ID.

Now you know which objects need refreshing.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "reload its data". How can I do it? I have NSFetchedResultsController and even if  I performFetch, nothing happens. I believe that NSManagedObjectContext on the iPhone app doesn't know about changes inside the persistent store. In that case, will existingObjectWithID work?

Comment: If the changes have been saved to the persistent store, `existingObjectWithID:` will work. You may need to use `shouldRefreshRefetchedObjects` to get fresh values from the store file. Also, after redoing the fetch, make sure to update the UI (table view, probably) displaying the data.

Comment: Thanks for the help Tom. It worked, but I also had to set stalenessInterval=0. If not, context didn’t see new objects. Not sure if it is correct way to do?

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the help. It would be nice if you could update the answer.